# Modal is transitioning error with bootstrap4 alpha6 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4 alpha 6 Modal, I am getting:

```
Error: Modal is transitioning
```

That happen when I am trying to re-trigger the same modal again with dynamic data through JavaScript function as following:

```
function openModal(title, text) {
    $('.modal-title').text(title);
    $('.modal-body p').text(text);
    $('#modalAlert').modal('show');
}
```

I tried to use setTimeout function, but didn't work as in this article:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21687

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's a bug https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/22334

Answer (score 10):

The quickest solution is to remove the modal 'fade' class which is throwing this error. It seems to be a known issue of the Bootsrap v6 that will be fixed in a next released.

See [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/21607)

Answer (score 4):

Worked with removing `fade` from parent div class.

Final Modal code ( *Adding here for posterity* ) :

HTML

```
<div class="modal loadingModal" id="applemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"  aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="ico/4.svg">
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getTimeline",
        data: {
            'dateTime': selected
        },
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function () {
              $('#applemodal').modal({
                  backdrop: 'static',
                  keyboard: false
              });
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#applemodal').modal('toggle');
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i am using bootstrap 4 Modal too, My solution;

```
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '.modal', function (event) {
        var zIndex = 1040 + (10 * $('.modal:visible').length);
        $(this).css('z-index', zIndex);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.modal-backdrop').not('.modal-stack').css('z-index', zIndex - 1).addClass('modal-stack');
        }, 0);
    });
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain what your code does? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First open the modal and then try to find the DOM elements that's inside modal (eg. `$('.modal-title')` and `$('.modal-body p')`)

Changing the order of executing your function might work:

```
function openModal(title, text) {
  $('#modalAlert').modal('show'); 
  $('.modal-title').text(title);
  $('.modal-body p').text(text);
}
```

Finally, make sure that modal is open/visible in the screen when you access HTML that's inside the modal.

Comment: has nothing to do with changing the DOM elements inside the modal, even when you don't change anything and try to open the modal multiple times when it's already open, the error happens

Answer (score 0):

Please set your button type='submit' to type='button'

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to open the model programmatically rather than through the link.

**Instead of:**

```
<A href="javascript: void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" title="Open My Modal">Open My Modal</A>
```

**Use:**

```
<A href="javascript: void(0);" ID="myLink" title="Open My Modal">Open My Modal</A>
```

```
$('#myLink').on('click', function(){ 
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
})
```